# Is it possible to increase size of an APFS volume?

Tags: disk-utility, disk-space

I've an APFS disk image (`disk3`). Currently it's capacity is near close; around 700 MB left.

Is it possible to increase it while keeping the data inside intact!

I've tried `diskutil apfs resizeContainer` but with no luck.

**diskutil list:**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            170.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS CAN                     499.7 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +30.2 GB    disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         29.9 GB    disk3s2

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +29.9 GB    disk4
                                 Physical Store disk3s2
   1:                APFS Volume cache                   29.3 GB    disk4s1
```

Comment: Post to your question, the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson please see the edit

Comment: Extra comment: [APFS sparse disk images and data loss](https://bombich.com/blog/2018/02/15/macos-may-lose-data-on-apfs-formatted-disk-images)!

Comment: @klanomath Yeah, that sounds interesting. I shall give it a read. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first increase the size of the disk image and in a second step the size of the container:

1. Get the disk image limits:

   ```
   hdiutil resize -limits /path/to/disk_image
   ```
2. Eject the disk image items:

   ```
   diskutil list
   diskutil eject diskXsY #eject all volumes/items of the image
   ```
3. Depending on the limits increase the size of the image:

   ```
   hdiutil resize -size <size> /path/to/disk_image #<size> in b|k|m|g|t (e.g. 50g)
   ```

   This works for normal as well as sparse images. I didn't test sparse bundle images.
4. Mount the disk image:

   ```
   hdiutil attach /path/to/disk_image
   ```
5. Get the details:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```
6. Increase the size of the APFS container:

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizeContainer <disk_identifier_apfs_container> 0
   ```

   Don't mix the disk identifiers of SSD and disk image APFS container here! The embedded APFS volume should be expanded automatically if required.

---

Using certain APFS formatted disk images (sparse images) may result in [data loss in the image](https://bombich.com/blog/2018/02/15/macos-may-lose-data-on-apfs-formatted-disk-images) on APFS formatted physical disks with low free space.

**Instead of using an APFS disk image simply create a new APFS *cache* volume (with quota?) in the APFS container (internal SSD) or an image/a second partition on an external HDD.**

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a new larger AFPS disk image.

In your case, the source would be the container `disk4`, as shown below.

```
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +30.2 GB    disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         29.9 GB    disk3s2
```

Below is the `diskutil list` output from a propose larger AFPS disk image target.

```
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +200.0 GB   disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk6         199.8 GB   disk5s2
```

You the could clone the source to the target by using the command given below.

```
asr  --source  /dev/disk4  --target  /dev/disk6  --erase
```

Or, the following could be substituted.

```
asr  --source  /dev/disk3s2  --target  /dev/disk5s2  --erase
```

> Note: Afterwards, both the source and target will be unmounted.

BTW, you can use the Disk Utility application instead of the `asr` command. This substitution seemed to succeed, when I tested. The only problem was the Disk Utility application hung afterwards. This required me to Force Quit the Disk Utility application. I was using macOS 10.13.3.