# APFS Volume does not increase in size

Tags: backup, apfs, big-sur, diskutil, sparsebundle

I have an issue with an APFS volume that resides inside a SparseBundle.
I tried to increase its size (similar to this: [Is it possible to increase size of an APFS volume?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315721/is-it-possible-to-increase-size-of-an-apfs-volume)), but failed.
Unfortunately, I have no idea what else to do (except for recreating the whole thing, copying all data, and put it in the place of the existing one).

---

**added (2020-12-08):**

I noticed that during the last step of my actions an error occurred and I assume that my problem exists because of the error.

The error happened during "Increase APFS Container" `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk2s2 0`

```
    error: (oid 0xa67b) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x5824c5de98a6fb78)
    fsroot tree is invalid
    The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely
```

---

### Setup

The setup I have an issue with is like this, however I think the relevant part is within the APFS part:

- On Mac OS (now Big Sur)
- SMB network share, usually mounted to `/Volumes/Backup/`
- On `/Volumes/Backup/` there is a SparseBundle  (`/Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle`)
- Inside the SparseBundle there is a APFS container with one APFS volume,
  the volume mounts to `/Volumes/itunes_backup/`
- On `~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/` I have a link to the mounted volume
  `lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  staff    29 Oct 14  2017 Backup -> /Volumes/itunes_backup/Backup`

What I wanted to do was increase the size of the APFS Volume which resides inside the SparseBundle.

### Steps I took to increase the APFS volume

1. Increased the size of the SparseBundle with this command:
   `hdiutil resize -size 1500g /Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle`
   As far as I could see, no error was thrown.
2. To check, ran `hdiutil imageinfo /Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle`

   ```
   Class Name: CSparseBundleDiskImage
   Size Information:
       Total Bytes: 1610822492160
       Compressed Ratio: 1
       Sector Count: 3146137680
       Total Non-Empty Bytes: 0
       Compressed Bytes: 1610822492160
       Total Empty Bytes: 1610822492160
   Checksum Type: none
   Format: UDSB
   partitions:
       partition-scheme: GUID
       block-size: 512
       partitions:
           0:
               partition-name: Protective Master Boot Record
               partition-start: 0
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 1
               partition-hint: MBR
           1:
               partition-name: GPT Header
               partition-start: 1
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 1
               partition-hint: Primary GPT Header
           2:
               partition-name: GPT Partition Data
               partition-start: 2
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 32
               partition-hint: Primary GPT Table
           3:
               partition-name: 
               partition-start: 34
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 6
               partition-hint: Apple_Free
           4:
               partition-UUID: 131BB16B-9C17-4ADE-BA9C-19A43E3F42F3
               partition-name: EFI System Partition
               partition-hint-UUID: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
               partition-start: 40
               partition-number: 1
               partition-length: 409600
               partition-hint: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
               partition-filesystems:
                   FAT32: EFI
           5:
               partition-UUID: D528609D-5A45-4146-92A8-871B833293BD
               partition-name: disk image
               partition-hint-UUID: 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
               partition-start: 409640
               partition-number: 2
               partition-length: 3145728000
               partition-hint: Apple_APFS
               partition-filesystems:
                   APFS: Untitled
           6:
               partition-name: 
               partition-start: 3146137640
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 7
               partition-hint: Apple_Free
           7:
               partition-name: GPT Partition Data
               partition-start: 3146137647
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 32
               partition-hint: Backup GPT Table
           8:
               partition-name: GPT Header
               partition-start: 3146137679
               partition-synthesized: true
               partition-length: 1
               partition-hint: Backup GPT Header
       burnable: false
   Format Description: sparse
   Checksum Value: 
   Properties:
       Encrypted: false
       Kernel Compatible: false
       Checksummed: false
       Software License Agreement: false
       Partitioned: false
       Compressed: no
   Segments:
       0: /Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle
   Backing Store Information:
       URL: file:///Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle/
       Name: itunes_backup.sparsebundle
       Class Name: CBundleBackingStore
   Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
    min     cur     max 
   1679163392  3145728000  18014398509072303
   ```
3. Mount SparseBundle
   `hdiutil attach /Volumes/Backup/iTunes_iOS_Backup/Backup_sparse_bundle/itunes_backup.sparsebundle`

   ```
   /dev/disk2              GUID_partition_scheme           
   /dev/disk2s1            EFI                             
   /dev/disk2s2            Apple_APFS                      
   /dev/disk3              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
   /dev/disk3s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Volumes/itunes_backup
   ```
4. Increase APFS Container: `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk2s2 0`
   **added:** I noticed that during this step an error occurred

   ```
   Started APFS operation
   Aligning grow delta to 510.612.738.048 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 1.610.612.736.000 bytes
   Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 1.610.611.707.904 bytes
   Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk3
   The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk2s2
   Verifying storage system
   Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk2s2
   Checking the container superblock
   Checking the space manager
   Checking the space manager free queue trees
   Checking the object map
   Checking volume
   Checking the APFS volume superblock
   The volume itunes_backup was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.47) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.50.1)
   Checking the object map
   Checking the snapshot metadata tree
   Checking the snapshot metadata
   Checking the extent ref tree
   Checking the fsroot tree
   error: (oid 0xa67b) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x5824c5de98a6fb78)
   fsroot tree is invalid
   The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely
   Storage system check exit code is 0
   Growing APFS Physical Store disk2s2 from 1.099.999.997.952 to 1.610.612.736.000 bytes
   Modifying partition map
   Growing APFS data structures
   Finished APFS operation
   ```
5. `diskutil apfs list`

   ```
   APFS Containers (2 found)
   |
   +-- Container disk1
   |   +-< Physical Store disk0s2
   |   +-> Volume disk1s1 
   |   +-> Volume disk1s2 
   |   +-> Volume disk1s3 
   |   +-> Volume disk1s4 
   |   +-> Volume disk1s5 
   |
   +-- Container disk3 E79238FB-8BB4-44AB-AFD9-4990B9B70F23
       ====================================================
       APFS Container Reference:     disk3
       Size (Capacity Ceiling):      1610612736000 B (1.6 TB)
       Capacity In Use By Volumes:   845079302144 B (845.1 GB) (52.5% used)
       Capacity Not Allocated:       765533433856 B (765.5 GB) (47.5% free)
       |
       +-< Physical Store disk2s2 D528609D-5A45-4146-92A8-871B833293BD
       |   -----------------------------------------------------------
       |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk2s2
       |   Size:                       1610612736000 B (1.6 TB)
       |
       +-> Volume disk3s1 424805EF-477B-4C7B-9688-9A46612478D9
           ---------------------------------------------------
           APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s1 (No specific role)
           Name:                      itunes_backup (Case-sensitive)
           Mount Point:               /Volumes/itunes_backup
           Capacity Consumed:         844815552512 B (844.8 GB)
           Sealed:                    No
           FileVault:                 No
   ```

### The trouble

The issue I have is that the volume seems not be enlarged or at least the space is not usable. When I tried to copy data to the drive it failed due to not enough space.

When I check with `df -h /Volumes/itunes_backup/` I see

```
    Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused       ifree %iused  Mounted on
    /dev/disk3s1  1.5Ti  787Gi  285Gi    74%  647844 15727992156    0%   /Volumes/itunes_backup
```

**Any ideas how I can proceed to increase also the APFS volume would be much appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to get rid of the error `error: (oid 0xa67b) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x5824c5de98a6fb78)` by creating a new SparseBundle and copying all data over to the new one.

#### My process

**A)**
Create a new SparseBundle including APFS container.
That gave me the possibility to use larger band size of ~60MB (instead of default 8MB).

`hdiutil create -size 1t -type SPARSEBUNDLE -tgtimagekey sparse-band-size=131072 -fs APFS -volname itunes_backup_new -attach itunes_backup_new.sparsebundle`

```
/dev/disk4              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk4s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk4s2            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk5              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk5s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Volumes/itunes_backup_new
```

**B)**
Clone all data from old APFS volume to new APFS volume.
I used the good old [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/), because it allows for incremental cloning. That means I could stop the cloning in the middle and continue without starting fresh.
Because it is content aware it only clones actual data. The result was a smaller SparseBundle.

**Alternative step B)**

I also tried `asr` out of curiosity on a copy of the original SparseBundle.
It worked fine as far as I can tell. The process is to create a new SparseBundle as described above in step A) and then run `asr`.
Because I wanted to get rid of the error of the APFS Container, it seems a good idea to use the option `--useInverter`, which copies data instead of replicating it.

`asr --source /dev/disk3 --target /dev/disk5 --erase --useInverter --buffers 1 --buffersize 1g`

#### What did not help me

- Diskutil repairVolume was unable to correct the error:
  `diskutil repairvolume disk5`

  ```
   Started file system repair on disk5
   Repairing storage system
   Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/disk4s2
   Checking the container superblock
   Checking the space manager
   Checking the space manager free queue trees
   Checking the object map
   Checking volume
   Checking the APFS volume superblock
   The volume itunes_backup was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.47) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.50.1)
   Checking the object map
   Checking the snapshot metadata tree
   Checking the snapshot metadata
   Checking the extent ref tree
   Checking the fsroot tree
   error: (oid 0xa67b) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x5824c5de98a6fb78)
   fsroot tree is invalid
   The volume /dev/disk4s2 could not be verified completely
   Storage system check exit code is 0
   Finished file system repair on disk5
  ```
- On reddit ([Disk Utility First Aid Error](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/a6ypex/disk_utility_first_aid_error_the_volume/)) is was suggested to run `fsck_apfs -y /dev/yourdisk`. Basically the same as diskutil repairVolume with more options, but did not help me.
- Tried `hdiutil convert` and it completed, but it was unable to correct the error. I assume this is because it has no awareness of the APFS container.
  However, without the error in my source the conversion works, of course.
  `hdiutil convert itunes_backup.sparsebundle -format UDSB -tgtimagekey sparse-band-size=131072 -o itunes_backup_131072.sparsebundle`

Answer (score 1):

> The [accepted answer you reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315721/is-it-possible-to-increase-size-of-an-apfs-volume) did not include the `-imageonly` option in the `hdiutil` command shown in step 3.

I am using High Sierra. Here is an Example.

First, I create a sparse bundle.

```
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ hdiutil create -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size 100g -fs APFS -volname MyAPFS -attach ~/Desktop/test
/dev/disk1              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk1s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk1s2            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk2              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk2s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Volumes/MyAPFS
created: /Users/davidanderson/Desktop/test.sparsebundle
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list disk1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +107.4 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         107.2 GB   disk1s2
```

Next, I eject.

```
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ diskutil eject disk1
Disk disk1 ejected
```

Here, is the resize command.

```
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ hdiutil resize -size 200g -imageonly ~/Desktop/test.sparsebundle
nx_kernel_mount:1359: : checkpoint search: largest xid 5, best xid 5 @ 9
nx_kernel_mount:1359: : checkpoint search: largest xid 5, best xid 5 @ 9
nx_kernel_mount:1359: : checkpoint search: largest xid 5, best xid 5 @ 9
nx_kernel_mount:1359: : checkpoint search: largest xid 5, best xid 5 @ 9
```

Next, I mount.

```
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ hdiutil attach ~/Desktop/test.sparsebundle
/dev/disk1              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk1s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk1s2            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk2              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk2s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Volumes/MyAPFS
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list disk1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +214.7 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         107.2 GB   disk1s2
```

Finally, I increase the size of the APFS container.

```
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0
Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 107,374,182,400 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 214,538,608,640 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 214,537,580,544 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk2
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk1s2
Verifying storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk1s2
Checking volume
Checking the container superblock
Checking the space manager
Checking the object map
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the snapshots
Verifying allocated space
The volume /dev/disk1s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Growing APFS Physical Store disk1s2 from 107,164,426,240 to 214,538,608,640 bytes
Modifying partition map
Growing APFS data structures
Finished APFS operation
Marlin-3:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list disk1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +214.7 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         214.5 GB   disk1s2
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the only difference is `-imageonly` in command `hdiutil resize -size 200g -imageonly ~/Desktop/test.sparsebundle`. Tried that, even with an old backup of the SparseBundle, but to no avail.
While I tried that I realized that there occurred an error during my last step: `error: (oid 0xa67b) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x5824c5de98a6fb78)
fsroot tree is invalid`. The problem was also present on the oldest backup I had from about 1yr back. It seems that at some point in the past my APFS container (or volume?) got corrupted.

Comment: Have to tried using `diskutil` to repair? You might be able to use `asr` to clone, but this would require enough free space as used by the current sparse bundle.

Comment: Space is not an issue. What do you suggest; on my layout described above `diskutil repairVolume disk3s1`? While I checked about `asr` i found [link to CCC](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/cloning-macos-system-volumes-apple-software-restore). If repair with `diskutil` fails, I might simply create a new SparseBundle and use CCC to clone the data. Will take a while for 900gb, but should work, right?

Comment: Or use `diskutil repairVolume disk2s2`. I noticed I deleted a post two years ago involving `asr` to the question [Is it possible to increase size of an APFS volume?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315721/is-it-possible-to-increase-size-of-an-apfs-volume) You may want to read this answer so I restored the post.